# kubectl get pods returns inconsistent results

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I execute `kubectl get pods`, I get different output for the same pod.

For example:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n ha-rabbitmq
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
rabbitmq-ha-0   1/1     Running   0          85m
rabbitmq-ha-1   1/1     Running   9          84m
rabbitmq-ha-2   1/1     Running   0          50m
```

After that I execute the same command and here is the different result:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n ha-rabbitmq
NAME            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
rabbitmq-ha-0   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   19         85m
rabbitmq-ha-1   1/1     Running            9          85m
rabbitmq-ha-2   1/1     Running            0          51m
```

I have 2 master nodes and 5 worker nodes initialized with kubeadm. Each master node has one instance of built-in etcd pod running on them.

Result of `kubectl get nodes`:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -owide
NAME              STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8s-meb-master1   Ready    master   14d     v1.14.3   10.30.29.11    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-51-generic   docker://18.9.5
k8s-meb-master2   Ready    master   14d     v1.14.3   10.30.29.12    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-51-generic   docker://18.9.6
k8s-meb-worker1   Ready    <none>   14d     v1.14.3   10.30.29.13    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-51-generic   docker://18.9.5
k8s-meb-worker2   Ready    <none>   14d     v1.14.3   10.30.29.14    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-51-generic   docker://18.9.5
k8s-meb-worker3   Ready    <none>   14d     v1.14.3   10.30.29.15    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-51-generic   docker://18.9.5
k8s-meb-worker4   Ready    <none>   14d     v1.14.2   10.30.29.16    <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS   4.15.0-51-generic   docker://18.9.5
k8s-meb-worker5   Ready    <none>   5d19h   v1.14.2   10.30.29.151   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04 LTS     4.15.0-20-generic   docker://18.9.5
```

Can this issue be related to unsynchronized contents for the `/var/lib/etcd/` in the master nodes ?

Answer (score 2):

Your pods are in `CrashLoopBackoff` state.
That means that some containers inside the pod are exiting (the main process exits) and the pod gets restarted over and over again.

Depending when you run the `get po` command, you might see your pod as `Running` (the process didn't exit yet) or `CrashLoopBackoff` (kubernetes is waiting before restarting your pod.

You can confirm this is the case by looking at the `Restarts` counter in the output.

I suggest you have a look at the restarting pods logs to get an idea why they're failing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still wonder why I see different numbers for the **RESTARTS** count each time I execute `get pods` command. For example the **RESTARTS** count for `rabbitmq-ha-0` was 0, then I execute `get pods` command again it says that **RESTARTS** count is 19. After that I execute `get pods` and the **RESTARTS** count becomes 0 again. I am facing an inconsistent situation.

Comment: For some reason the pod gets recreated. Are you sure the pod name you're checking the restarts count is the same?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that. I think that the main cause for this issue is the different data on each etcd pod running on the master nodes.

Comment: Can you please verify that by using `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>`?

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is a ETCD inconsistence between each control nodes due to a incomplete etcd restoration. Please refer this link to how to do it properly https://medium.com/@pranaybhardwaj007/etcd-backup-and-restore-in-ha-mode-8722b97d440d